# How can you download/export an object in JSP to a file stored remotely?

Tags: java, jsp, serialization, objectoutputstream

I'm using JSP and I have a complex serializable object that I want to be downloaded into a flat file format to the client computer. How can this be done?

I can get the object to save locally to the JSP server using ObjectOutputStream but I need the object to be stored remotely to the JSP server and never locally (e.g. to the clients storage)

Once the object is stored on the clients computer locally, I then want to be able to upload it back to the JSP server and opened/read into an object, how can this be done?

Kind Regards,

Tim

Comment: This line looks ambiguous.. I can get the object to save *locally* to the **JSP server** using ObjectOutputStream but I need the object to be stored *remotely* to the **JSP server** and never locally. Please explain this a bit more; do you mean downloading on the local computer vs saving on the app server?

Comment: Hi @gyan, I mean downloading the object on to the local computer. E.g. I need the object to be serialized and saved on client computer and not the JSP server. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is not possible for a JSP server to write **automatically** to a network location. This is a security restriction and may not be possible without a manual request to application. You may want to use below strategies:

1. Create a shared location at client machine (assuming, it is on network) and mount the location on your server, then code the JSP to save the file at that location.
2. Save the file on JSP server location, then an FTP transfer script can be written to transfer file to client machine; using a job scheduler (needs FTP communication to be established).
3. Code the application in such a way that it could be downloaded using the application website (like a music file is downloaded). Then at client side, you may run a program, which will connect to the app server and programatically save the file at the client machine.

Comment: Thanks @gyan for your response and suggested strategies. I had a different strategy in mind but just not sure if its possible/how to code it. Would it be possible push the object into a ObjectOutputStream object which can then be pushed into a FileOutputStream object which could trigger a download of the file?

Comment: This could work in strategy #1, where the FileOutputStream would write the file on a location (which is eventually a shared client directory). Otherwise, without a client permission (which is why a download through browser is always asked for permission to save) it is not possible to save a file on disk. Imagine, your program would have a potential to save a virus quietly on client's machine :) (if it is possible to save directly from a web application)

Comment: Hmm but could it not trigger a file download in the way that you download files normally from a website, e.g. click a link and be asked where to save the file?

Comment: But you need a client application (strategy #3) to do that and then  indirectly you would be *giving a permission* to the client application to save the file. Think it like a download manager software hitting a URL and saving file for you automatically. Whole idea is that someone need to trigger the download.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is **sending a binary object over http**.

You can use the following code snippet in the JSP code.

```
response.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=myjavaobject.obj");

ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
oos.writeObject(yourJavaObject); //Assuming yourJavaObject is the java object you want to send.
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Do not forget to make sure that `yourJavaObject` is `serializable`.

Comment: Thanks @Santosh, this is exactly what I am looking for except this causes one extra issue. As I'm using JSP which uses getWriter(), I can't then call getOutputStream() as you can't call both due to it causing 2 requests. How can I get around this issue? Kind Regards, Tim